# Unable to return value in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I am doing a problem in leetcode where I am supposed to return the index of the specific target, here's the code:

```py
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        l=len(nums)
        for i in range(0,l):
            if(nums[i]==target):
                print(i)
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: None is not valid value for the expected return type integer
    raise TypeError(str(ret) + " is not valid value for the expected return type integer");
```

I was expecting the index to return

Comment: You should return it, not print.

Comment: Well, return it using `return i` instead of print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **return the index** instead of printing it.

```
class Solution:
    def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> int:
        l=len(nums)
        for i in range(0,l):
            if(nums[i]==target):
                return i
```

Comment: you should add some logic for the case that `target` is not found. In that case, the function would still return None

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am not giving accurate solutions for the problems. 
It may be possible that the problem statement states `the target value will be always available in the list.`

Answer (score 1):

You don't return a value, you print it.

`print(i)` should be `return i`

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Solution:
       def searchInsert(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> Optional[int]:
           l=len(nums)
           for i in range(0,l):
               if(nums[i]==target):
                   return i
```

If no `return` in your function, `None` will be returned as default, and in your code, just `print(i)` couldn't break the `for` loop.
Follow the comment, the `searchInsert` will return `None` if could find the index.

Comment: you should add some logic for the case that `target` is not found. In that case, the function would still return None

Comment: Good suggestion, change the type hint, I think return None is pretty suitable here, right?